# Laravel return values missing from documentation?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

In the [Laravel documentation](http://laravel.com/docs), I can't find the possible return values are for basic Laravel functions like:

```
Mail::send(...)       // does this return true/false if successful?
Input::get('foo')     // what is returned when foo is not set?
Request::segment(2)   // what is returned if there isn't a second segment?
```

Have I overlooked something or are we just left to trial/error to figure these out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Take a look at the Laravel API website for all the source code.  It's extremely well written and easy to follow.  You should be able to answer all of these questions and learn new features very quickly.

=========================================

Laravel being as big and powerful as it is, makes it hard to document every little thing.  However, using the API site, you can find answers to all these questions and discover TONS of neat, undocumented little tricks and treats.

[Laravel API](http://laravel.com/api/)

**`Mail::send()` Example**

Take for instance your `Mail::send()` example.  At the API site, we can search for Mail and browse to the `Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php` [page](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Mail.Mailer.html).

From there we can look at the code for the `send()` *[Line 94](http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Mail.Mailer.html#94-121)* method and see that it returns a call to `$this->sendSwiftMessage($message)`.

From there, we can take a look at the code for the `sendSwiftMessage()` [Line 281](http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Mail.Mailer.html#281-297) method and see that it returns a call of `$this->swift->send($message)`.

Looking through the Mail class, we learn that `$this->swift` is simply a instance of the Swift_Mailer class [Line 56](http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Mail.Mailer.html#56-67).  The Laravel docs actually do [mention](http://laravel.com/docs/mail) that the Mail class is a wrapper for the popular Swift_Mailer.

Anyway, now we need to find what the `send()` method in the Swift_Mailer library returns.  Where we see at the Swift_Mailer [website](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html), the `send()` method actually returns the number of recipients it was sent to, or `0` upon a failure.

> Swift_Mailer itself actually have available quite a bit more useful
>   information, such as who the actual failed recipients were.  However,
>   Laravel does not expose this information as of now.  If you wanted to
>   gain access to `Swift_Mailer`'s other features, you'd have to either
>   extend the `Mail` class or perhaps use the `Swift_Mailer` class
>   directly.

This essentially means, that yes, you can use a true/false check to determine success as `0` will evaluate to false and any positive, non zero number will evaluate to true in PHP.  However, I also believe that Laravel will throw an exception if something goes wrong as it does in most cases, however this might be a, forgive the pun, exception where it will not throw an `Exception`.

Although that was a bit long winded, and probably one of the more complex examples.  The vast majority of things Laravel provides are quick, easy to lookup and understand.

Going through the API is a great way to discover tons of undocumented features of the framework.  For example, just go to the [`Str`](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Support.Str.html) class and you'll see quite a few neat, useful things that you can use.

**`Input::get()` Example**

Without going into as much detail, `Input::get` ends up calling the `array_get()` helper function [Link](http://laravel.com/api/source-function-array_get.html#226-251), which will return the following in order of priority.

1. The value stored at the key.
2. The default value passed to the `Input::get()` method.
3. null

Comment: Thank you for the info and work-around. Perhaps I am spoiled but when I look at docs for a function I expect to see a list of possible return values. Documentation for PHP as well as other PHP frameworks do list the return values. Seems like a terrible omission by Laravel to me. Digging in the source code is a great way to learn about the nuts and bolts of a framework, but I don't want to do it just to figure out possible return values.

Comment: @Justin I agree with you for the most part.  However, Laravel is incredibly well written.  So much so, that it in fact makes finding basic things like return values through the source not only feasible, but preferable in some cases.  The actual "docs" should really only be seen as a starting point.  Once you know how the basics work, you should always refer to the API, which once you learn how to navigate, is really quick.

Comment: I am not an phpdoc expert but it seems the "return void" docblock notes indicate it doesn't return anything at all. Things like this with no mention of the return value in the docs *does* make it difficult at times.

Comment: hi i have tried with $count = Mail::send( with all required parameter);  echo $count;  if i try it with wrong email or true email it always gives me count 0.  can you please let me know is there any way to check email send or not .

Comment: FYI, all your links to Laravel docs are now broken. They updated their URL scheme .. Doh! :/